# How can i add a icon to submit button Yii?

Tags: php, button, yii

Html button is

`<button class="btn" type="submit"><i class="icon-search"></i> Go</button`>

I changed it into Yii as

```
<?php
echo CHtml::submitButton('Go', array('id' => 'btSubmit',
    'class' => 'btn', 
    'name' => 'files'
));
?>
```

How can i add  to button

Comment: What HTML does that block of PHP code output?

Comment: According to the `yii` source code the `CHtml::tag` method requires a third parameter to submit internal content. The `CHtml::button` method does not pass this through, so you can't add internal HTML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work

```
  echo CHtml::tag('button', array(
        'name'=>'btnSubmit',
        'type'=>'submit'
      ), '<i class="icon-search"></i> Go');
```

will generate

```
<button name="btnSubmit" type="submit"><i class="icon-search"></i> Go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton(
    CHtml::tag('i', array('class' => 'icon-search')) . ' Go', 
    array('id' => 'btSubmit',
        'class' => 'btn', 
        'name' => 'files')
);
?>
```

Use **CHtml::tag('i', array('class' => 'icon-search')) . ' Go'** instead of **'Go'** in your code.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [yii source code](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#submitButton-detail) the `CHtml::tag` method requires a third parameter to submit internal content. The `CHtml::button` method does not pass this through, so you can't add internal HTML.

Using the `tag` method directly should work however:

```
echo CHtml::tag('button',[
  'id'=>'btsubmit','class'=>'btn','name'=>'files','type'=>'submit'
],'<i class="icon-search"></i> Go');
```